# Initialize function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to get the address of a method (the method is called EndScene) it is a function of a D3D9 object and assign it to my function pointer.

But when i have the address i have trouble assigning it to my function pointer, this is the code i'm using:

```
    typedef HRESULT (IDirect3DDevice9::* EndSceneFunc)( void );


    IDirect3DDevice9* pTempDev = ...;
    // get the address of the virtual table
    BYTE* pVtable = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>( pTempDev );
    // assign the address of the EndScene function to the function pointer (error)
    EndSceneFunc endsceneFunc = pVtable + ( sizeof(void*) * EndSceneIndex);
```

The error i'm getting is: A value of type BYTE* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type EndSceneFunc.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: i must do this by walking the vtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a pointer-to-member-function, not the address of the function (assuming that is what's stored in the vtable, and assuming that your shenanigans actually give you the vtable entry). The language provides a straightforward way to get that:

```
EndSceneFunc endsceneFunc = &IDirect3DDevice9::EndScene;
```

> EDIT: i must do this by walking the vtable

You can't, sorry. Why do you think you need to do that?

> i want to patch it and replace it with my own function

In that case, you don't want a pointer-to-member-function at all, and you're far beyond the realms of defined behaviour. You might try something like this:

```
// Reinterpret the pointer to the device as a pointer to a pointer 
// to a table of pointers, hoping that its first member is a pointer
// to the vtable (which hopefully contains pointers to functions).
void *** ppVtable = reinterpret_cast<void***>( pTempDev );

// Indirect through that to get (hopefully) the pointer to the vtable
void ** pVtable = *ppVtable;

// Hopefully overwrite an element with a pointer to your function
pVtable[EndSceneIndex] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(myFunction);
```

Comment: This actually works, thanks but i now realise im making a mistake the pTempDev i created should actually be assigned to another device thats already been created by another process. That's why i do need to walk the vtable. Can't you think of another solution?

Comment: @JonathanD: I've no idea what you mean; you don't need `pTempDev` at all to get the pointer, and you can use it on any `IDirect3DDevice9` once you've got it. If you mean you need to call the function on some device using this pointer, then call it on an object as `(device.*endsceneFunc)()`, or on a pointer as `(device->endsceneFunc)()`.

Comment: I do not want to just call the function, i want to patch it and replace it with my own function. that's why i think i need to walk the vtable, right?

Comment: @JonathanD: I've updated the answer with something that might do something along those lines; but as far as C++ is concerned, you're on your own. I suggest rethinking what you need to do, and doing something within the C++ type system.

Comment: Thanks i will do some more research and for now ill just accept this.

Answer (score -1):

```
EndSceneFunc endsceneFunc = pVtable + ( sizeof(void*) * EndSceneIndex);
```

This line here is your problem, as pVtable is of type `BYTE *`. Try casting it to the type of `EndSceneFunc`.

```
EndSceneFunc endsceneFunc = reinterpret_cast<EndSceneFunc>(pVtable + ( sizeof(void*) * EndSceneIndex));
```

Comment: That might force it through the compiler, but you'll get horrible runtime errors if you ever try to use it.

Comment: Yeah, you really should just try what Mike said if what you want is to point to a specific function. I was just trying to explain why you had an error.

Answer (score -1):

This is presumably a generic pointer to member function initialization (from the syntax) in which case Mike Seymour's answer is generically how you would go about it. It is different if you want a pointer to a static member function then it has ordinary function pointer type.

Comment: When you say patch what do you mean? You can re-assign a pointer to member function in the same way you initialized it if you want to change it to a different member function of the same class with the same signature which is kind of the whole point of pointers to member functions. If you want to change it to a function with signature HRESULT generic_function_name(IDirect3DDevice9*) if you're feeling really brave some compilers might accept it (not to be recommended).

Comment: Why the downvote? At the time I added this Mike Seymour's answer was not complete and did not mention this was known as pointer to member functions as far as I remember which is useful if anyone wants to do further reading.